# Importar função de um Pod - CoCoaPods Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou começando agora com Swift (Xcode 7), fiz a instalação do cocoapods, porem queria saber como faz para importar as funções que existem no pod para um projeto novo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Cria um projeto novo no XCode. Fecha o XCode.
2. Abre o terminal e navega até a pasta do projeto
3. Digita `pod init` e dá enter. Isso vai criar um arquivo chamado `Podfile`. Abre esse arquivo em um editor qualquer.
4. A estrutura do arquivo é mais ou menos assim:

   ```
   platform :ios, '9.0'
   use_frameworks!

   target 'MyApp' do

   end
   ```
5. Troca `'MyApp'` pelo nome do projeto do teu aplicativo
6. Entre o `do` e o `end`, coloca as bibliotecas que você quer usar desse jeito (vou colocar 3 bibliotecas como exemplo):

   ```
   target 'MyApp' do
       pod 'Alamofire'
       pod 'PKRevealController'
       pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   end
   ```
7. Fecha o arquivo, volta pro terminal e digita `pod install`
8. Quando o programa acabar de baixar e configurar tudo, ele vai criar um arquivo chamado `<NomeDoSeuProjeto>.xcworkspace`. Abra esse arquivo. A partir de agora, só mexa no projeto a partir dessa workspace. Se você abrir o projeto sozinho (como é feito normalmente), as bibliotecas não vão estar lá e o XCode não vai conseguir construir o seu projeto. Uma workspace é apenas um projeto que junta vários projetos em um só, para facilitar nossa vida.
9. Do lado esquerdo, na aba de projetos/arquivos, vai aparecer o teu projeto e um projeto extra, onde vão estar instaladas as bibliotecas que você baixou.
10. O Cocoapods configura o link automaticamente, é só importar as bibliotecas (isso é muito importante, você precisa importar explicitamente as bibliotecas que você instalou) no teu código e usar normalmente.
11. Pode acontecer de o XCode não reconhecer a biblioteca e emitir um erro quando você importá-la primeira vez. Basta dar *build* (Command-B) que isso é corrigido.

Comment: Olá Lucas, primeiramente agradeço a ajuda, porem acho que não fui claro, pois essa parte eu ja fiz...o que me falta saber é como eu chamo uma função que esteja dentro do pod importado. Eu estou querendo utilizar as funções do codigo: https://github.com/richa008/CurrencyTextField

Comment: dentro do pod tenho a classe "class CurrencyTextField", então dentro dessa classe eu verifiquei que existe uma função: func getCleanNumberString(), eu queria utilizar essa função para somar os valores das textfield.

Comment: Então Luan, dei uma olhada na classe e essa função é privada, ou seja, só código escrito naquele mesmo arquivo pode acessá-la. Você tem duas opções:

1. Editar o código da biblioteca, tornando a função pública ou criando uma função nova;

2. Escrever a tua própria função, que pega o texto do `CurrencyTextField` e faz exatamente o que a função `getCleanNumberString()` faz.

Comment: entendi Lucas, irei fazer como disse e digo o que aconteceu, caso ela fosse public como eu chamaria dentro do meu ViewController?

Comment: Depois de inicializar (`let c = CurrencyTextField()`), você pode acessar como `c.getCleanNumberString()`.